# What `primaries` and `deleted documents` columns in opensearch dashboard mean

Tags: opensearch-dashboards

[image]

Please have a look at this picture from OpenSearch Dashboard. This table can be found under `Index Management -> Indices`

1. Total size is 45gb and primaries is 22gb, does it mean that this index takes 67gb in general of disk space?
2. Deleted documents count is too big. Can anyone explain whether this count takes some space on disk or not? I read multiple specs but still not sure how to interpret it. I tried making force merge on some other index and Deleted documents count did not decrease at al and I did not see any more disk space after this merge so I'm not sure how to deal with this deleted documents.

Thank you everyone who can help.

Answer (score 1):

Primaries will be the primary shards, total size will be primary + replica shards. In this case you have 1 replica, so 22GB primary + ~23 GB for the replica.

Deleted documents could be retained for archive purposes. To check I'd probably create a new index, injest some docs and then delete all of them. If the size is greater than zero it would suggest its retaining deleted docs data.